# Solaris 11 development environment on Cloud or hosting

Tags: oracle, solaris

I got in charge to create a website based on Java. Production environment specs include Solaris 11.1, OHS 12.1.3, WebLogic 12.1.3, Java 1.7.0_51 and Oracle Database 11.2.

I want to create a server on some cloud or hosting service as Development environment with the same specs to avoid migration problems to Production. I also think this approach helps to give my team a single server where they can work and have some testers/client to visit the site.

Normally I would use a local Development environment but a lot of people is involved and differences with Production can become a problem at migration.

I checked http://www.polarhome.com/ but I don't know if it will fit all specs needed. I looked at Windows Azure and Google Cloud with no success. AWS maybe? I also checked https://cloud.oracle.com but I don't understand if they already offer what I need.

Do you know any providers to create my Development environment or another approach/suggestion to develop this project??
Thanks!

EDIT.

To clarify, the client's Production environment already exists and is running somewhere. My project will be installed on that environment when development is finished. I personally think that developing on any VM with WebLogic 12.1.X and Oracle Database 11.X should be enough, but I've never done it so I wanted to follow client's advise on having a Development environment similar to Production.
Do you think I can just create a VM on any OS and just install WebLogic 12 with Oracle Database 11?? Any suggestions to avoid migration issues if I take that route?

Answer (score 1):

I think that develop a new website from scratch thinking to use the architecture proposed by you is a nonsense. I think that if you will use cloud services like PaaS you will do something better.
In any case, you can find solaris VMs on [Cloudsigma](https://www.cloudsigma.com/cloudsigma-launches-native-oracle-solaris-based-iaas-offering-for-the-enterprise/) , [Entic](http://entic.net/Servers) and Oracle Public Cloud

Comment: Thanks. I didn't propose the architecture. It's already running somewhere with a couple of other websites. The project I was assigned to will just sit on that existing production environment. I was suggested to create a development environment with the same specs because in the past there have been issues when migrating (they say). I think any VM running WebLogic 12 should be enough. I visited Entic and Cloudsigma. Entic login page has an expired SSL certificate and is from 2011 so I got doubts. I had a chat with CloudSigma service and they say Solaris is not available today.

Comment: Do you think I can create a VM on any OS and just install WebLogic 12 / Oracle Database?? I think that should be fine because it's finally a Java project, but I haven't worked with WebLogic and I don't know what issues to expect when migrating to production.

Comment: Weblogic is a nightmare :)
I think you can install Solaris on an Intel x86 VM and then install all other products on this server. This is a perfect setting to test the migration

Comment: @user2997817 *I was suggested to create a development environment with the same specs because in the past there have been issues when migrating (they say).*  Migrating from *where*?  Where is development done *now*?

Comment: *I think that develop a new website from scratch thinking to use the architecture proposed by you is a nonsense.* Why do you think that?  Is there anything *wrong* with such a solution?

Comment: @Andrew Henle: I would mean that if you are developing a new web site and you need/want to run it in a cloud environment, you shouldn't have to worry about Operating System. I'm sure that is very unuseful running Virtual Machines in a cloud and install Application Servers or databases. It is right only for legacy applications. When you develop new applications for cloud you have to focus your attention only on Platform as a service or on serverless architecture. Do you agree?